# ANT Ivy version 1 Vs 2

Tags: ant, build-process, ivy

```
 <ivy-module version="1.0"> Vs <ivy-module version="2.0">
```

Does any one can please list me the differences between Ivy version 1 and version 2. My system

is  would like to know when should i decide to upgrade to version 2.

Comment: Did you read the release notes ?

Comment: Versioning configuration files is good practice to protect backward compatibility. Always use the latest version. This is not the same thing as the version of ivy (version 1 of ivy no longer available for download).